# Cannot click two digit number while Automating Google Calculator using Selenium

Tags: selenium

I need to write a code where
a) Go to www.google.com and search for 'calculator'. In the results you will see a calculator coming in the browser itself.
b) Read the Num1 from xls using java code
c) Click the Num1 in calculator of google

Excel File is simple and looks like this.

Num1

7

95

I hope you people understood. 
First row Num1
Second row 2
Third row is 95

Using @Test I have written a code
The problem is, I can click Num1 7 but not 95. 
Moreover if my num1 is 2 also, it throws me error. Please help.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Exercise3 {
    String part1 = "//*[@id='cwbt";
    String part2 = "']/div/span";



        @Test(dataProvider="getData")
        public void calculator(String num1, String num2, String operation, String expectedResult){
            WebDriver d = new FirefoxDriver();
            d.manage().window().maximize();
            d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            d.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=2ArXVu7RGafG8AfjsKPgDQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=calculator");
            //calculator box
            //*[@id='cwbt13']/div/span
            //*[@id='cwbt23']/div/span
            //*[@id='cwbt33']/div/span
            //*[@id='cwbt43']/div/span
            WebElement box = d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='cwmcwd']"));
            for(int i=13;i<=46;i++){
                String num = d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='cwbt"+i+"']/div/span")).getText();
                if(num.equals(num1)){
                    d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='cwbt"+i+"']/div/span")).click();
                    break;
                }
            }

                }
        @DataProvider
        public Object[][] getData(){

        Xls_Reader xls = new Xls_Reader("E:\\Pessoal\\QTPSelenium\\Excel\\Calculator.xlsx");
        int rows = xls.getRowCount("Addition");
        int cols = xls.getColumnCount("Addition");

        Object data[][] = new Object[rows-1][cols-2];

        for(int rNum=2;rNum<=rows;rNum++){
            for(int cNum=0;cNum<cols-2;cNum++){
                System.out.println(xls.getCellData("Addition", cNum, rNum));
                data[rNum-2][cNum] = xls.getCellData("Addition", cNum, rNum);

            }
        }
    return data;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try following code/ I have updated according to Java Lang

```
 FirefoxDriver driver;        
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=2ArXVu7RGafG8AfjsKPgDQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=calculator"); 
    String strJavaScript = "document.getElementById('cwos').textContent= " + num1.trim() + " " + operation.trim() + " " + num2.trim() ;
    Object obj;
    //org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor.class.
    obj = driver.executeScript(strJavaScript, (Object) null);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cwbt45']/div/span")).click();
    String answer = driver.findElement(By.id("cwos")).getText();
    if (expectedAnswer == null ? answer == null : expectedAnswer.equals(answer)) {
        System.out.println("Expected answer and given answer are same.");
    }
    else        
                    System.out.println("Expected answer and given answer are not same.");
    System.out.print(answer);
```

if any issue then let me know.

Comment: Hi @Muhammad, Given code is full of comments. I am facing issues. Please help

Comment: Yes i commented your code and written two new lines to do all work. which you were using in loop. One more thing it is written in c# because i don't have java platform to write. But you just make syntax according to java it'll work.  I have tested it and it is working code. to calculate.

Comment: Know check code. Hope so you understand. I have updated according to java language.
If still any issue then let me know.
Thanks.